# Sending XML Response When Maxed Allowed Connections Reached to Servlet

Tags: java, http, jboss, servlet

I have a requirement to limit the number of incoming connections, and if another connection is initiated as the limit is reached to send an XML response. This is for JBoss EAP 6, but a general standard servlet solution would work. How should I handle this? We don't exactly know the remote destinations for the inbound connections.

My first thought was to a develop a filter, but I have no idea how I would find out the number of open connections to a path.

Comment: Try set `max-connections` in the HTTP Connector. See https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/http.html

Comment: How do I configure the HTTP connector to reply with an XML response body?

Comment: Ok, now I understand the question, maybe the best approach to this would be to use a filter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563442/how-to-set-limit-to-the-number-of-concurrent-request-in-servlet

Comment: I don't see anything in your recommendation that covers how to tell how many connections have been opened to a particular URL. Could you clarify, please?